# Set div by default active

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have 3 div's and 3 buttons each button on click reveals one div but what im trying to achieve is to set div-nr1 to be by default displayed
this is the angular code that im using...

```
 var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('Test',function($scope){
            $scope.show = 1;    
    });
```

this are buttons

```
<ul>
              <li class="has-subnav" ng-click="show = 1">
                <a routerLink="/dashboard">
                          <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                      </a>

              </li>
              <li class="has-subnav" ng-click="show = 2">
                <a routerLink="/projects">
                          <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>   
                      </a>
              </li>
              <li class="has-subnav"ng-click="show = 3" >
                <a routerLink="/teams" >
                          <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </a>
              </li>
             </ul>
```

and this is one of the div's

```
<div class="information-boxes" ng-show="show==1">
           <ul class="box-docs" >
               <li>
                <div class="docImages">
                <img src="../assets/images/lp.png" alt="">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just init the `show` variable in the markup like below?

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="show=1">
```